# Zen Cart language packs

Tags: php, zen-cart, language-packs

I have one [Zen Cart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart) website in the English language. I want to make the same website in French and Italian languages. How can I do this?

I mean, if I install language packs for Zen Cart, will this convert all the site and data inside the database in that language or do I have to type data again in particular language?

What is the URL to download the above language packs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For downloading the Zen Cart language packs, open http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=40_46.

Answer (score 0):

Most general Zen Cart language text is held in files for versions up to and including Zen Cart 1.5. So installing the language packs for those languages will deal with a lot of your needs for French and Italian. But not all of it.

Category and Product information is held in the database and installing a language pack will not automatically translate that to a different language, you will need to arrange that yourself.

Zen Cart also allows you to insert blocks of HTML (through the define_pages editor) such as on the home page, or explanatory text on the shopping cart page. If you have used text in these HTML blocks, then you will need to translate that too.

A major exception on many sites would be pages created using Zen Cart's built in CMS, EZ-Pages. If you've done this, you will need to install the Multilingual EZ-Pages add-in module and then translate the pages created this way.

One final, and rare exception, would be if you have created any HTML banners. Most people don't so if you're not sure what this means, it probably doesn't affect you.

Answer (score -1):

For download language pack, visit here: first link.

There is all language pack that have this cms, after this read this topic in main forum of cms: second link

I think that you know how upload your language pack in your web server...

http://nopaste.voric.com/paste.php?f=227xgw